# Click same button to refresh current page and navigate to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on a jquermobile template (only one HTML page with 10 DIVs as **data-role=page**) and I have a scenario where I have one button which when clicked should perform two activities at the same time -

1. Refresh the forms (that means.. reset the form fields)
2. Navigate to home screen

For this I am doing two things -

1. An `onClick` function that calls `location.reload()` - to refresh the page
2. For the same button, added an anchor tag referring to a screen (which is a DIV tag in jquerymobile template).

The problem here is, only the `location.reload()` works and the anchor tag fails to navigate to the given link (e.g. `a href="index.html/#myDiv"` - this doesn't do anything)

Can anyone suggest me an approach or provide me a working example for the above scenario, in which both the functionalities work for the same button?

Comment: `a` does not work when you set PreventDefault=true or stopPropation().. or return=false;

Comment: It would easier with some code...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is when you do a reload it lost the track and never redirect you, so you can manually clean the entries and then reload to other page

- First clear all the values
- then navigate away to other page

these both step will be perform sequentially

```
  function SomeName()
     {  
      document.getElementById('elementid').value = "";
       ....
       ....
      document.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html'; 
     }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following
In the script
`<script>
    function clickEvent(){
        refresh();
        navigate to home();
    }
</script>`

in html 
`<input type="button" value="Dont show this again! " onClick="clickEvent();" />`